# Filter List of Object-Nested Objects with Object Containing Key-Array Pair

Tags: javascript, arrays, filtering, javascript-objects

I tried to came up with the most descriptive title.

I came up with a solution but its terribly inefficient as its in the order of O(n^4) or so, which is pathetic.

I am trying to filter and return a list of objects based on a filter-object and matching key values.

I will have a list of movies, `movieList`, and I will return all movies that meet all the key-value pairs that are contained within the `movieFilter` object. In the case of `genre`, the movie must be one of the genres. Since sales is not in the filter we do not filter based on it.

```
let movieFilter = {
  "genre": ["Action", "Romance"],
  "director": "Bob",
  "writer": ["Jim", "Dave", "Alice"],
  "duration": "2"
}

let movie = {
  "genre" : "Action",
  "people": {
    "director": "Bob",
    "writer": "Alice"   
  }
  "boxoffice": "9,000,000",
  "duration": "2"
}

let movies = [{
  "genre" : "Action",
  "people": {
    "director": "Bob",
    "writer": "Alice"   
  }
  "boxoffice": "9,000,000",
  "duration": "2"
}, 
{
  "genre" : "Comedy",
  "people": {
    "director": "Rose",
    "writer": "Mike"   
  }
  "boxoffice": "12,000,000",
  "duration": "3"
}]
```

The issue I'm having is that because some filters (like the `genre` filter) are in arrays and some movie keys (like `people`) are nested within an object I am forced to nest loops within loops, which makes the time complexity grow.

I could change the way the filter is structures, but the way it currently is makes sense to me. The movie object format is something I cannot change.

Any suggestion on how I could tackle this would be appreciated.

Comment: Please include your filter code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider replacing your arrays with objects inside your movieFilter.

```js
let movieFilter = {
  genre: { Action: true, Romance: true },
  director: "Bob",
  writer: { Jim: true, Dave: true, Alice: true },
  duration: "2"
};

let movies = [
  {
    genre: "Action",
    people: {
      director: "Bob",
      writer: "Alice"
    },
    boxoffice: "9,000,000",
    duration: "2"
  },
  {
    genre: "Comedy",
    people: {
      director: "Rose",
      writer: "Mike"
    },
    boxoffice: "12,000,000",
    duration: "3"
  }
];

const filterOnMovieFilter = movie => {
  const { genre, people, duration } = movie;
  const { writer, director } = people || {};
  return (
    movieFilter.genre[genre] &&
    movieFilter.writer[writer] &&
    movieFilter.duration === duration &&
    movieFilter.director === director
  );
};
console.log(movies.filter(filterOnMovieFilter));
```

However, please avoid [premature optimization](https://stackify.com/premature-optimization-evil/).  You will not notice optimization when filtering 10,000 items in a modern browser.
(Notice I said filter and not display)   I often do things that are less efficient in favor of simple, concise, immutable, readable and useful code.  If you are targeting a feature phone or  find a real performance bottleneck, you will need to measure with performance monitoring tools.  The JavaScript engine optimizations are continuously improving and results are often surprising.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done using `filter` method and `some` method:

```js
let movieFilter = {
  "genre": ["Action", "Romance"],
  "director": "Bob",
  "writer": ["Jim", "Dave", "Alice"],
  "duration": "2"
}

let movies = [
  {
  "genre": "Action",
  "people": {
    "director": "Bob",
    "writer": "Alice"
  },
  "boxoffice": "9,000,000",
  "duration": "2"
},
{
  "genre": "Comedy",
  "people": {
    "director": "Rose",
    "writer": "Mike"
  },
  "boxoffice": "12,000,000",
  "duration": "3"
}]

const result = movies.filter(f => movieFilter.genre.some(ge=> ge == f.genre)
                                  && movieFilter.director == f.people.director
                                  && movieFilter.writer.some(wr => wr == f.people.writer)
                                  && movieFilter.duration == f.duration
                            );
console.log(result);
```

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to @MkeSpaGuy comment. I've remade a little bit approach to filter your items.

It is slightly optimized version using `key` to check whether filter conditions are satisfied:

```js
let movieFilter = {
  "genre": ["Action", "Romance"],
  "director": "Bob",
  "writer": ["Jim", "Dave", "Alice"],
  "duration": "2"
}

movieFilter.genre = movieFilter.genre.reduce((a, key) => ({...a, [key] : 1}), {});
movieFilter.writer = movieFilter.writer.reduce((a, key) => ({...a, [key] : 1}), {});

let movies = [{
  "genre" : "Action",
  "people": {
"director": "Bob",
"writer": "Alice"
  },
  "boxoffice": "9,000,000",
  "duration": "2"
},
{
  "genre" : "Comedy",
  "people": {
"director": "Rose",
"writer": "Mike"
  },
  "boxoffice": "12,000,000",
  "duration": "3"
}];


const result = movies.filter(f => movieFilter.genre[f.genre]
                              && movieFilter.director == f.people.director
                              && movieFilter.writer[f.people.writer]
                              && movieFilter.duration == f.duration
);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I do like me some, but think @WhatAmIDoing is looking to avoid array searches inside the filter.

Comment: @MkeSpaGuy Thanks for your great comment! Please, see my updated answer.

Comment: So we now have the same answer, but you are just showing how to programmatic convert array to to object / lookup map.   I'm using destructuring and using a named function.

Comment: @MkeSpaGuy One task, different ways:)